# Unity3D Facebook SDK Webplayer New User gets null reference

Tags: facebook, facebook-unity-sdk

Our code has been In Production on a Facebook canvas app for some time now but today one of our testers said he couldn't use the app if he logs out then into another account.

The same thing happens when a new user trys to play our app.

I pushed the Facebook Interactive Console App to one of our production environments and we're getting similar results.

Init gets hit and works. But when the user is not authenticated and the log in is called, It brings up a Permission Dialog. They gets accepted but the SDK still says the user is not logged in. In the log is this:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at Facebook.CanvasFacebook.OnFacebookAuthResponse (System.String responseJsonData) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Facebook.JsBridge.OnFacebookAuthResponse (System.String responseJsonData) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

When log in is called again it flashes the dialog for less than a second and throws that error again. On reload of the app, the same issues.

Comment: Hi David, to clarify: nobody can login to your app? when any player accepts the permissions dialog, it fails, is that correct? Can you post the link to your test app? Also, try this app: https://apps.facebook.com/unity_vfourtwofour/ and let me know what happens. One random and unlikely thought is an app id mismatch.

Comment: Couple of updates. We made a new FB App and put the Facebook Demo project on it and the tester that had the issues could play it perfectly. Unlike when he played it in our main development app. We took it a step further, put out current game on the new app low and behold it works just fine. So it leads me to believe that something in our app settings on Facebook is causing this issue. I opened the app settings in two tabs and compared each and every option and they're configured exactly the same. There's only 1 difference. The development app has another setting in it that the new app doesn't.

Comment: The development app has a setting for "Enhanced Auth Dialog" and the newly created app doesn't. From research it looks like all new apps have this feature defaulted to enabled, which is what the development app is currently configured to.

Comment: Is this error still happening?  Trying to repro this.

Comment: I have seen this error also so can confirm it still exist (v5.0.4 of the facebook sdk). I've not tested this thoroughly but I believe the error is occurring because the user hasn't accepted tester invitation for the given app. As soon as I accepted the tester invite I found that I could log on with the new user no problem.